# Android SDK tools r12 update on Linux

Tags: android, linux, sdk

I use ubuntu 10.04. I update Android SDK tools to r12 version. When I start my AVD with scale from 0.5 to 1.0 I get 256-colors screen. What is it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a known bug with Linux r12 and scaling in the emulator:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18299