# Adjusting scale of emulator causes color distortion

Tags: android

From Eclipse:
Run > Run Configurations > target tab . I added '-scale 0.75' to the command line options bar.  Then I hit F11 and ok to run the emulator.  The colors are completed distorted.  Without using the scale option the colors are fine, but the window is too big.

Edit:  It looks like I can go up to scale 0.49 without any color distortion, but the emulator is still a bit too small for me to see easily.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with android emulator "-scale" option. Lossy picture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621684/problem-with-android-emulator-scale-option-lossy-picture)

Comment: Also covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627351/android-sdk-tools-r12-update-on-linux